# Draw 2d graph with y-axis, x-axis

Tags: java, swing, awt, 2d, java-2d

[image]
How to draw 2d graph with y-axis, x-axis which begin with 0,0 coordinates and  all values in positive direction?

It must be started at left bottom of canvas. y-axis and x-axis also need to draw in the canvas.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I did somthing like this AffineTransform yUp = new AffineTransform();
yUp.setToScale(0, 0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `AffineTransform` (or combination of them) to flip the y value, and shift 0,0 to the bottom left of the component.

Comment: @Andrew, see the attachment,I'm creating an object(with predefined width and height) in the canvas. also that object might be rotate with angle in the canvas. any suggestion to handle it with coordination?